# C++ Get GPS Time from 32-bit Integer

Tags: c++, time, gps, epoch

Sorry if this sounds confusing, but I have a program that I am writing that needs to retrieve the GPS time (Epoch time) in minutes from a Nav unit. The Nav unit sends out a 72 byte UDP packet. According to the Nav manual, bytes 63, 64, 65, and 66 contain the 32 bit GPS time. I have tried to retrieve the time correctly but the time seems to be out. The value I'm getting is around 18754849 where i'm pretty sure the current GPS time should be around 24020957 according to [this](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

The code I am using to retrieve the time is below. This was from a person who was working on the program previously and my maths isn't very good so I am not sure if it's right or not. Can anyone see any obvious errors here? Also this is where the buf value comes in.

```
iResult = recvfrom(sock, buf, sizeof (buf), 0, 0, 0);
```

Thanks

```
minutes = (unsigned char)buf[66]*0x1000000 + (unsigned char)buf[65]*0x10000 + (unsigned char)buf[64]*0x100 + (unsigned char)buf[63];
```

Comment: Be aware that there is something called [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) due to 32-bit integers.

Comment: Glad you have solved your problem.  One other thing to consider is that it's more normal to use bit shifts and bitwise-or instead of multiplication and addition when reconstructing a value from big- or little-endian: `buf[66] << 24 | buf[65] << 16 | buf[64] << 8 | buf[63]`.

Comment: Thanks for that, it does seem a lot easier to do it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my own problem. Turns out the GPS time is from Jan 6th 1980 where the EPOCH time is from Jan 1st 1970. I thought they were the same thing, I feel pretty stupid now. Thanks anyway